# What is the effect of ACLs/umask on the permissions of the executable file generated by gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, acl, umask

I have been wondering how `gcc` determines the resulting file permissions of the executable file being generated. To gain some insight, I considered a minimalistic program `test.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  int fd = open("output.dat", O_CREAT, 0777);
  close(fd);
}
```

and the following two scenarios:

1. The file `test.c` resides in a directory without ACLs and umask is set to `0027`. If I execute `gcc -o test test.c`, the file `test` has (as expected) permissions `rwxr-x---` and so does the file `output.dat` created by launching `./test`.
2. The file `test.c` resides in a directory with `setfacl -m d:g::rX -m d:o:--- .` and umask is set to `0022`. Under these circumstances the executable file `test` generated by `gcc` has permissions `rwxr-x--x` while the file `output.dat` retains `rwxr-x---`.

As for the file `output.dat`, the behavior seems to be in agreement with the section *Object creation and default ACLs* in the manual page of acl. Further, `strace` reveals that `gcc` first creates the output file and `chmod`s the executable flag later. However, it seems to call `chmod("test", 0750)` in the first scenario and `chmod("test", 0751)` in the second one.

I am probably missing something very obvious but what is the reason for the `0751` permissions in the latter case? Shouldn't `-m d:o:---` be respected?

Comment: I suspect GCC calls `chmod` explicitly because it wants th execute permissions to depend on whether the compilation succeeded or failed.

Comment: Ah, yes, this I understand (I think) - I was wondering why it kind of "overrides" the default ACLs...